# Google Chrome "Back" and "Forward" History

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a little extensions called "[Tab Bundler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooajenhhhbdbcolenhmmkgmkcocfdahd)", which in short saves all the open tabs in a window into a bundle that can be opened with the click of a button. When a bundle is opened however, no history of how the user got to that url is saved, ie. the user can't click back to see how they got to that url. This is functionality I want to implement. I looked for a while, googling, looking thoroughly through the google chrome extension documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html. But I couldn't figure out how to get this information without tracking it myself. Is that the only option I have? Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone developed something [similar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/faminaibgiklngmfpfbhmokfmnglamcm) already.

Comment: I feel like its actually quite different. That extension has the intention of hiding tabs that aren't appropriate to be viewed later, whereas my extension has the intention of saving multiple tabs in groups so that people can organize tabs of the same type together for easy access at a later time. Thanks for the input anyways.

Comment: Finally! Great idea, keep going!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, many people tried this before.  You are not alone in this quest!
At the moment the answer in Google Code was: anybody asked for it when they where developing the History API.  Then there's no elegant way to access tabs' history.
Of course, you can hook [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) to record every page and make your own tab's history...

Comment: sure, thanks for the answer. I actually realize that tracking it myself might not even work because I dont think there is a way of adding URLS to the history stack (or whatever container they use, and dont quote me on this because I haven't done much research).

Comment: there is a (horrible) way to put your url into the tab history: Actually navigating (automatically) trough the pages, for example, giving 2 seconds for each page to load, until you reassemble the tab history :)  Well, nobody is perfect.

Comment: Do you have any references to Google Code where one could look up the precise circumstances that make accessing a tab's history difficult? I was planning to take a closer look at the issue on the Chromium side.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably hook chrome.tab.onUpdate as well as some state or focus change hook to correlate.

I really want this, please make it!