# Retrieve History of a specific Tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get the history of a chrome tab?  I know chrome stores it *somewhere* (holding the 'back' button displays it), but I don't know if it's available to chrome extensions.  If it isn't, I may be able create a workaround with content scripts (essentially building an array of the history from messages), but that's not ideal.

My goal here is to detect when a certain page is loaded, and then record the URL of the page that was previously loaded.

Comment: [Google Chrome "Back" and "Forward" History](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9981267) - nothing's changed since then, you'll have to manually hook chrome.tabs.onUpdated

Comment: Thanks for the help!